I can't navigate to another screen
I'm trying to navigate to a completely different screen in WPF. I don't want to open a new window, just to navigate within the same.
I want to re-render an entire different screen.
Here is my code :
<Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}"
        Content="Plotp"
        Margin="0,10,0,0"
        Height="50" Width="400" 
        Click="PlotButton" />

Here is my C# file:
using Plot.View.Screens;
.....
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PlotButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //UserControl uc = new Plot();
            //MainFrame.Navigate(uc);

            MainFrame.Content = new Plot();
        }
    }
}

And here I render my other file, the thing is that it's still in my previous screen and it's not rendering anything, but inside my C# file, it enters and I can see my boxmessage:
<UserControl x:Class="................Plot"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:...."
             xmlns:mdc="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             Background="#1E2C39">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Border Grid.Row="0">
    <oxy:PlotView Name="SpectralPlot"
                  Width="400"
                  Height="400"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Background="Transparent" />
</Border>

So what is the problem?
Thanks

It sounds like what you're describing is that you want to change the DataContext of your View. Typically, to do this, you would pass a different ViewModel to the View's DataContext.

Screenshots may help with exactly what you are trying to do. Using Frames and Pages sounds like what you are trying to do but, as others have mentioned if the controls don't change just the data then you should just change the DataContext.

Hello guys sorry for the late answer..i manage to do it with a viewModel architecture and i was needed 2 extra files for some reason the RelayCommand and ObserableObject ... i never touch  mvvm architecture ,i was mainly familiar with mvc .Can i ask 1 more question ? can i avoid mvvm or is by default the main solution ? Can i use controller instead? Also why i need "commands" realys and all of this...i just want to navigate for a screen or keep some state for my components-widgets.Do i also need viewModel with relay commands for state management?Im kinda confused..Thanks in advance.
